# how to block a process for certain time in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, command-line

I am running a automatic incremental backup in network, at that time if thunderbird is running on client computer then backup is not completed that's why i need to know if there is any command to block a process for certain time for example thunderbird etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the SIGSTOP signal to any process and that process will stop execution, this signal can't be ignored by the process. To send the signal by PID of the process run:

```
kill -STOP THE_PID_OF_THUNDERBIRD
```

To send the signal to every process running a specified command, e.g. thunderbird, use this :

```
killall -STOP thunderbird
```

To allow the process to continue execution just send the process the SIGCONT signal:

```
kill -CONT THE_PID_OF_THUNDERBIRD
```

or

```
killall -CONT thunderbird
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [falconer's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/394642/72576), you can have a command-line way and a graphical way to achieve what you want to achieve:

### Graphical method:

1. Type "System Monitor" on your dash and open the "Processes" tab. You'll see the list of process currently running(don't worry to see some unknown processes running, the kernel runs a lot of process in the background to keep everything in place that you see running).
2. Right-click on the process you want to temporarily suspend and click on "Stop process"(NOT "End process"). This will suspend execution of the process temporarily and you can resume later by clicking on "Continue process".

[image: stop and continue process execution]

### Command-line method:

Open a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type:

```
pkill -STOP process_name
```

OR

```
killall -STOP process_name
```

Eg.

```
pkill -STOP thunderbird
```

To continue execution of the process:

```
pkill -CONT process_name
```

OR

```
killall -CONT process_name
```

Eg.

```
pkill -CONT thunderbird
```